# How would you say "familiar foreign land" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am trying to translate the lyrics of [the Eric Bogle's song "The Gift of Years"](https://youtu.be/5_plvOvyBik) into Latin. In the second stanza, there are verses:

> And for the last time here I stand,
> in this **familiar foreign land** (later in the song revealed to be a war graveyard where his comrades are burried).

How would you say that in Latin? My attempt would be:

> Et ultimo tempore hic sto,
> in hac extranea terra de qua plenitatem scio.

Comment: Not your question, but "for the last time" is "postremum" or "extremum" or "ultimum". "Ultimo tempore" means something like "at the final moment".

Comment: Why *plenitas*? To my ear it sounds as awkward as English "about which I know a plenitude." It's a rare, post-Augustinian word. Latin tends to favor the concrete over the abstract, and *a fortiori* in a case like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for something like this:

```
in hac terra aliena non incognita
```

or

```
in hac terra aliena non ignota
```

The double negation `non ignota` gives it some extra emphasis and distinguishes it from `aliena`. I think that prevents the confusion that may occur when two adjectives succeed each other immediately.

The double negation `non incognitus` can be found in Cicero as well (Post Reditum in Senatu LCL 158: 92-93):

```
nec mihi ipsi ille animus idem meus vobis non incognitus defuit
```

Here it means "you do know (my strength)".